# Turning Off Chrome Sleep Mode

Tags: google-chrome

Friends, hello,
Google Chrome puts inactive tabs into sleep mode after a certain period of time to improve performance. Even if we disable the performance throttling option in the browser settings, the sleep mode remains active. When it enters sleep mode, JavaScript code stops running. As a result, AJAX requests cannot be made. I would like to ask if anyone among us has experienced and resolved this issue before, or if you have any thoughts on how to solve it.

Previously, this feature could be disabled through Chrome settings, but unfortunately, in the latest version, such an option is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension can probably help you: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok?hl=en

Alternatively, you can turn off memory saver by going to chrome://settings and  going to the Performance section.